# File url plays totally fine, but download url cannot be played

Tags: flutter

I use record flutter package to record audio. when i play the recorded audio this way, it worked: await _player.play(DeviceFileSource(file.path));

I then tried this: await _player.play(UrlSource(downloadUrl));  but it doesnt work; i got this error:  AudioPlayers Exception: AudioPlayerException(
I/flutter (30205):  UrlSource(url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anonmous-37821.appspot.com/o/audio%2F485eb730-7b24-11ee-9a7f-0543cca0e333?alt=media&token=9d2bb57d-a5a5-4a88-a13d-465a281a9784),
I/flutter (30205):  PlatformException(AndroidAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN {what:1}, MEDIA_ERROR_SYSTEM, null).

I was convinced that there may be a problem with the package i use in attempting to play the sound so i did this: await _player.play(UrlSource('https://www.studystack.com/nicebeep.mp3')); and it works.

How can i make the downloadurl work? as you may have seen, audio is uploaded to firestore.

Here is the full code :

uploadaudioFile(String path) async {

```
AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer();

print('the audio path $path');
String soundID = const Uuid().v1();
final _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
File file = File(path);
print("the real path ${file.path}");
bool fileExists = await file.exists();
print('File exists: $fileExists');
try {

  var snapshot = await _firebaseStorage
      .ref()
      .child('audio/$soundID').putFile(file);


  var downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  print('durl $downloadUrl');

  await _player.play(DeviceFileSource(file.path)); /// this works fine
  await _player.play(UrlSource('https://www.studystack.com/nicebeep.mp3')); /// this works as well
  await _player.play(UrlSource(downloadUrl)); /// this never works. All were tested separately.

  return downloadUrl;
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint(e.toString());
  print('Error uploading file ');
  return 'error';
}
```

}

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL does not specify a file ending. This could cause the audio player to act up. This problem is also described here in the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#ios-macos-urls-or-paths-without-a-file-extension)

These are your options:

- Make sure that your files have the appropriate ending (.mp3) when uploading them to blob storage
- Download the file, then add ".mp3" to the filename, then open it with your audio player.

Comment: No that doesnt work. I also did a few changes so that the uploaded audio is mp3. When i click the link(downloadurl) it plays perfectly when i open it in a browser, but same problem as mentioned when i try to play the audio using this: await _player.play(UrlSource(downloadUrl));

Comment: Are you on version 5.2.0 of the audioplayer package? This version is known to be buggy at the moment: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1669

Comment: Yes guys it was solved; what i did was record the audio in mp3 format using the record package instead of flutter_sound. Thanks for your. answers though.